# Incorrect json output from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I made a request from MySQL and my code below is not working:

```
$email =$_POST['email'];  
$parola =$_POST['parola'];

$rez = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM utilizatori WHERE email='$email' AND parola='$parola'");

if($rez){
    $succes = 1;
} else {
   $succes = 0;
}

$data = array("succes" => $succes);
echo json_encode($data);
```

In postman it shows me this:
[image]

Comment: Which means your query failed, please echo `mysqli_error($con)` to see the error message.

Comment: where is data variable?

Comment: do `$rez = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM utilizatori WHERE email='$email' AND parola='$parola'") or die(mysqli_error($con));` and check error

Comment: Also your SQL is open to SQL injection, please use prepare statement for better security

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318368/mysqli-or-die-does-it-have-to-die

Comment: This output is correct because your code return, $data = array("succes" => $succes);  json_encode($data);

Comment: Use mysqli_fetch_assoc function to fetch result as an associative array, then combine with $data array. $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez);  $data = array("succes" => $succes, "data" => $row);

Answer (score 0):

You missed the data variable or your query doesn't not return any output. Please try to use the MySQL query in `Phpmyadmin` or CLI. If it is OK then use the code like :

```
$email =$_POST['email'];  
$parola =$_POST['parola'];

$rez = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM utilizatori WHERE email='$email' AND parola='$parola'");

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($rez))
{
 $data[] = $result;

}
if(mysqli_num_rows($rez) != 0) {
    $data = array("success" => "Success", "data" => $data );
} else {
    $data = array("success" => "Failed", "data" => array() );
}

echo json_encode($data);
```